# Tracking interactions of a Single page Application in an Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have an iframe which contains a single page application, And I am looking to record actions within the form and hits to the page because it’s a single page app, do we need to add event tags to trigger the GA recording, as currently the page does not change URLs as you move through the form.

For Example “example.com” content is served in an “iframe” from a sub-domain (account.example.com/tba) that is a Single Page Application.How can I track interactions from it

Also help me with the GTM implementation

Comment: `Also help me with the GTM implementation` - that's quite a broad question - which part are you having the troubles with

Comment: GTM implementation in an Iframe so that tracking can be done.Please note that contents in a GTM is a SPA (Basically a form) so i need to track counts of clicks.

Comment: Does the `src` of the iframe have the same domain as your site? If not, you probably will not be able to interact with the page in the iframe due to the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: I take it you've read the [Quick Start](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/quickstart) and [Developer](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide) guides? Anything in them help you at all?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes mate have read it entirely not much of a help.

Comment: @KyleLin Yes the iframe src is same as the domain.

Comment: For Example “https://www.example.com” content is served in an “iframe” from a sub-domain (https://account.example.com/tba) that is a Single Page Application.How can I track interactions from it

Comment: Your question is far too broad; your question spans GA strategy, event tagging, pageview recording, SPA interactions, iframe tracking, virtual URL's and GTM implementation. I suggest you narrow your focus to an easily answerable question.